# Obtener ruta especifica de Crystal Report

Tags: rutas

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio en la cual debo de imprimir un **crystal report** donde tomo su ubicación de la siguiente manera:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)) + "\\Reports\\POH2.rpt";
```

Pero esta forma ya no me funciona al momento de realizar un ejecutable, alguien con alguna idea de como obtener la ruta específica del **Crystal report?**

Comment: Has probado a poner barras dobles en la ruta?Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)) + "\\Reports\\POH2.rpt";

Comment: Si de echo ya lo intente.

Comment: Windows? Linux?

Comment: Es windows 8.1 .

Comment: Has probado a hacer string cadena=Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)) + "\\Reports\\POH2.rpt"; ver el contenido de cadena y comprobar en el explorador de archivos si corresponde la carpeta e informe?

Comment: Si, en ese momento acceso a la ruta del reporte cuando lo corro desde VS, pero si lo hago ejecutable deja de funcionar.